# Not finding empty rows

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to put together a little script just to identify which rows of my table are empty, the code I am using is below, the problem it returns rows that are empty and full.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
$query = "SELECT ip_start_range, id FROM blocklistip";
$result = mysql_query( $query );
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {  
    if(isset($row['ip_start_range'])) { ?><br /><br /><?php
        echo $row['id']; ?><br /><br /><?php
    } else {
        echo '<p>" No Result "</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use the `WHERE` clause in your SQL query to filter out those rows?

Comment: Why don't you just check for "IS NULL" or "= ''" or "= 0" (define empty, as John Conde said) in the database query itself?

Comment: `isset()` will always be true. You might try `empty()`, or actually query for only empty rows in your sql statement.

Comment: Ha, Lion beat me to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work as you want because `$row['ip_start_range']` is always set, since you fetch it from query results.

Instead, filter the records with a `WHERE` condition:

```
$query = "SELECT ip_start_range, id FROM blocklistip WHERE ip_start_range IS NULL";
```

Or, if the field `ip_start_range` does not allow NULL, you can filter by empty strings:

```
$query = "SELECT ip_start_range, id FROM blocklistip WHERE ip_start_range=''";
```